# SQLAlchemy mysql dialect error with py2app

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyqt, py2app

I'm having trouble getting SQLAlchemy to work with my compiled app after getting through py2app. I've done this successfully in Windows with py2exe. The following is my setup file:

```
APP = ['Blah.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'includes': ['sip',
                        'PyQt4._qt',
                        'sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql',
                        'MySQLdb',
                        "gzip"]
           }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

This appears like it's the right way to do it, as I've seen people use it for sqlite, however I still get this error upon trying to run the app after compile:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine dialect for 'mysql+mysqldb'`

I've recently been trying with PyInstaller and have gotten stuck at pretty much the same spot, albeit with a different error which is the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 96, in <module>
   File "/Users/tom/Downloads/pyinstaller-pyinstaller-2145d84/PyInstaller/loader/iu.py", line 386, in importHook
     mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
   File "/Users/tom/Downloads/pyinstaller-pyinstaller-2145d84/PyInstaller/loader/iu.py", line 480, in doimport
     exec co in mod.__dict__
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
   File "/Users/tom/Downloads/pyinstaller-pyinstaller-2145d84/PyInstaller/loader/iu.py", line 386, in importHook
     mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
   File "/Users/tom/Downloads/pyinstaller-pyinstaller-2145d84/PyInstaller/loader/iu.py", line 480, in doimport
     exec co in mod.__dict__
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
   File "OSX_Installer/Jango/build/pyi.darwin/Jango/out00-PYZ.pyz/pkg_resources", line 882, in resource_filename
   File "OSX_Installer/Jango/build/pyi.darwin/Jango/out00-PYZ.pyz/pkg_resources", line 1352, in get_resource_filename
   File "OSX_Installer/Jango/build/pyi.darwin/Jango/out00-PYZ.pyz/pkg_resources", line 1363, in _extract_resource
 KeyError: '_mysql/_mysql.so'
```

Comment: Im assuming that you have http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/ installed, with appropriate version(s), which version of python do you have? I take it works fine without calling py2app.

Comment: I do, and I'm running 2.7. And yes, it works when running the python file as usual.

Comment: ok, is this the default version of python that ships with Mac OS X or your own installed version, it could be that py2app is referencing the systems while when you test it, its referencing yours, it could also be an issue with the paths not being properly set.

Comment: have you tried http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: I have, and am not stuck at roughly the same spot, albeit with a different error. See OP.

Comment: Ok now that's a more interesting error, I'll take a look once I get to my system, but it looks like the MySQL share object isn't being included in the build, since it looks like its being reference relatively, maybe it's a bug, try placing it manually and seeing what happens, check if it's there...

Answer (score 1):

you probably also need `_mysql` which should include the native mysql bindings. also, this bindings need the binary mysql libraries to be installed on the target system.

your application would probably be a lot more portable if you used a pure python mysql library, such as [pymysql](http://www.pymysql.org/) or [MySQL Connector/Python](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy) (both are [supported by sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql))

Comment: No luck, tried an easy_install with both and added _mysql to the includes list and I'm getting the same error. Any other ideas? :/